# Filter URL Query Strings For SQL Injections - PHP

Tags: php, sql-injection, xss

I've been given a site to fix that was recently hacked using SQL injection. From what I can gather the Havij automated SQL injector was used to insert code into the query string parameters of the url.

The site is a custom CMS build and a bit dated. I don't think a full rebuild is likely.

What's the best way to prevent this from occurring again? I'm a PHP developer, but usually just do validations on forms, or use systems that have this functionality already built in - wordpress, codeigniter, drupal etc.

Any ideas or thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one simple rule: **every** variable (doesn't matter where it came from - from user or it is something already gotten from database) that is being put into the sql query should be sanitized with `mysql_real_escape_string()` before.

Or you could use prepared queries (prepared statements/placeholders), doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, any quoted variable (strings).  Don't run MRES on integers and floats, just cast them to that before adding it to the query: `' AND id = ' . (int) $id`

Comment: @ircmaxell: indeed, just did not want to make things complex for OP.

Comment: Yeah the simple answer is more my cup of tea. Thanks all the same @ircmaxell

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to change all of the code, but maybe you can change the database code. If so try using PDO and prepared statements. I recommend pdo because you didn't specify the database type. If you are using mysql, I think mysqli also provides prepared statements.

Comment: Yeah I just used the mysql_real_escape_string() function on the variable before it went to the database. Less stessful / work than i thought it was going to be. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);